# Custom Built Combo Box Check Box

Tags: c#, linq, combobox, checkbox

I have a custom built combo box check box. I have taken it from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/extending_combobox.aspx

The drop down consists of 5 items, namely A, B, C, D, All.

What I wanna do is when the user checks All, uncheck A, B, C, D.
and when the user selects, either of A, B, C, D uncheck All.

I cannot figure out which logic should i put in.

I have tried this:

```
int index = ComboCheck.FindString(@"All");

foreach (var x in tComboCheck.CheckBoxItems.Where(y => y.Checked))
 {
  if(x.Text.StartsWith("A"))
    {
     ComboCheck.CheckBoxItems[index].Checked = false;
    }
  if(x.Text == @"All")
    {
     x.Checked = true;
    }
 }
```

It does not work. I am using this code under Checked Changed event. Please help

Comment: What a terrible, horrible, completely non-standard, and impossible to use control. Is there something wrong with regular checkboxes, or maybe a `ListView` with checkmarks?

Comment: not much space in my application. User demand :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler is better.

- Figure out what the user just did (checked "All" or checked something else)
- If user checked "All"

  - For each other item, uncheck it
- If user checked something else

  - Uncheck "All"

Ignore when users uncheck an item.

Don't try to lump these into one loop statement, it just gets confusing that way.